# What is the difference between Translucency and Transparency?

Tags: materials, shaders

I have been wondering this for a while. What is exactly the difference between a translucency shader and a transparency shader?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_and_translucency) allows light to pass through without refracting or scattering it, while [translucency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_and_translucency) scatters light to some degree.

What the manual says about the [*Transparent shader*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/transparent.html#transparent-bsdf):

> Transparent BSDF without refraction, passing straight through the
> surface, as if there was no geometry there. Useful with alpha maps for
> example. This [shader affects light paths somewhat differently than
> other BSDF's.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html#light-paths) Note that only pure white transparent shaders are
> completely transparent.

The [Translucent shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/translucent.html#translucent-bsdf) is more like a [Refraction shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/refraction.html#refraction-bsdf) with a high *Roughness* and an *IOR* of 0 (no refraction) It is also a little bit like an [SSS shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/sss.html#subsurface-scattering) in that light is scattered when passing through. (The main difference between the two is that the translucent shader scatters light more uniformly)

[image]

To visualize this using the manual images:

- The [Transparent](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/transparent.html#transparent-bsdf) shader lets light straight through:

[image]

- The [Translucent](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/translucent.html#translucent-bsdf) shader scatters light:

[image]